# My speech.listen(source) in python is taking stalling

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I am currently using the SpeechRecognition library, and when I do `audio = speech.listen(source)`, it seems like it stalls. There is no execution of code after it. I remove ambient sound, but it still seems to stall and have no effect on what my mic is picking up. Microphone works when I look at my computer's settings and it is unmuted.

I create an `pyttsx3` instance called engine, and a `sr.Recognizer()` instance called speech. I then call `getVoiceCommand()` to get some audio from the user(me) which goes to `print("Listening...")` and then it stalls.

The code after `audio = speech.listen(source)` does not execute, and when the timeout of 10 seconds is done, it gives me the WaitTimoutError, which hints out to me that it never picked up a sound? I tried changing the energy_threshold for values between 50 and 4000 and still didn't pick up any noise.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import pyaudio

def speak(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()

def getVoiceCommand():
    voice_text = ''
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            speech.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
            print("Listening...")
            #speech.energy_threshold = 4000
            print(speech.energy_threshold)
            audio = speech.listen(source, timeout=10)

        print("Stopped")
        voice_text = speech.recognize_google(audio, language='en-US')
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("Unknown value error")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print('Network error.')
    except sr.WaitTimeoutError:
        print(audio)
        print("Wait timeout error")

    print(voice_text)

engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.setProperty('voice', voice_id) # voice_id is chosen voice


rate = 220
engine.setProperty('rate', rate)

speech = sr.Recognizer()
getVoiceCommand()
```

Comment: There is an issue with this post. You you haven't made it reproducible by providing us with some sort of code for us to wrap our heads around. Post the code, the error, and then update the question.

Comment: I have changed the question. Thanks for that feedback @RedgarTech on my question. Hopefully the new edits give you contxt on mu problem

Comment: Thank you for doing that! I am a bit of a critic. Yes I will try to help you solve this. I have done a very similar program. I added an answer. You can tell me if it works or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used this program with the exact same libraries. This is assuming you have a microphone of some sort. If this doesn't work, its most likely background noise it is trying to detect as an input which in that case, you would need to add `r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=1)` Tell me if this code below works...

```
engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')   #Only use sapi 5 if it is Windows 10
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id) #This bit goes below the imports


def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)     #This bit right here goes below the above
    engine.runAndWait()



def takeCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()

    with sr.Microphone() as source:

        print("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        print("Recognizing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-us')
        print("User said: {query}\n")

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print("Google was unable to hear")
        return "None"

    return query
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: I used your exact same code for testing purposes since it worked for you, but it keeps stalling at the same spot. I added the `adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=1)`, but the terminal stays at "Listening..." . I am sure it is not my microphone since it is on and at a good input level. Also, I don't know if this helps, but I am using VS Code working on MacOSX.

Comment: And you are sure you have the two packages installed correctly? This includes Pyaudio and `speech_recognition`. Especially Pyaudio because it acts as the bridge between the mic and the computer and vice versa. Also, I use Pycharm. I never had any need to `import pyaudio`.

Comment: In case you didn't know. Pycharm is an IDE for Python and in my opinion, better for Python because it makes installing packages really easy and it even finds mistakes for you. In some cases, fixes them.

Comment: Alright, it works! I tried running the python script from my command line instead of from the VS Code editor and it worked. It is funny that VS Code was blocking my microphone from being able to hear anything, but it works perfectly running it from my command line. THanks for the help!

Comment: Do you might accepting the answer? This could help others as well. I'm glad that I could help!

Answer (score 0):

I tried some of the answers replied for this post. My code works perfectly when I am in an anechoic chamber. To overcome the case where the previous isn't True, I just used ambient noise in my source.

```
   
        import pyttsx3
        import speech_recognition as sr  
      
        engine = pyttsx3.init()
        voices = engine.getProperty('voices') 
        engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id) 
        rate = engine.getProperty('rate')                         
        engine.setProperty('rate', 190)
        engine.runAndWait()

        r = sr.Recognizer() 
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source) 
        print("Listening......")
        r.pause_threshold = 1 
        audio = r.listen(source)
```